# Rails avoid N+1 query problem working with external and internal data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following array coming from an external source :

```
documents = ['Doc Name 1', 'Doc Name 2', 'Doc Name 3', ...]
```

I want to loop through the array, and find details about the documents in my db (model `Doc`) if it exists.

```
documents.each do |document|
  puts Doc.find_by_name(document).details if Doc.find_by_name(document)
end
```

Of course this code works, but how can I avoid the N+1 query problem?

Comment: What is `details` is it an association to another table or it is a column in `docs` table?

Comment: `details` is a column in table docs

Comment: Then I believe the answer bellow is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope `details` is one of the columns in the table `docs`(plural of the model)

Try the below:

```
documents = ['Doc Name 1', 'Doc Name 2', 'Doc Name 3']

Doc.where(name: documents).pluck(:details)
```

It will trigger single query and selects value only the column `details` and returns the details in an array:

```
SELECT "docs"."details" FROM "docs" 
  WHERE "docs"."name" IN ('Doc Name 1', 'Doc Name 2', 'Doc Name 3')
```

If you have more data on the array `documents` please consider using batch processing.